# Closed subspaces which don't split

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analysis

Does someone have examples of a closed subspace of a Banach space which doesn't split it, please ? My underlying question is qualitative : are such pathological examples really exotic (and closed subspaces "generically" split) or are they quite common ?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. A Hilbert space is always the direct sum of any closed subspace and its orthogonal complement. If that does not answer your question, please [edit] to clarify what you mean by "split".

Comment: One interpretation would be for the space to fall apart in two connected components. Is that what you mean, @Alfred?

Comment: @EthanBolker : indeed, I apologize ! I meant for Banach spaces. Split in the sense that there is a continuous projection from the total space to the subspace